# Одноклассники спамят в метрике и статистике как будто заходит новый посетитель со 100% отказом?

Tags: modx, яндекс-метрика, одноклассники

у меня сайт автоматом по api постит в группу. Каждый раз когда он это делает, это фиксирует метрика как нового посетителя и как факт отказ. Как исправить данный момент? Не знаю даже куда копать. Теоретически, Одноклассники идут сканировать контент по ссылке, чтобы хотя бы взять изо. Но парсинг в тот же вк не оставляет следов. Буду очень признателен за идеи... [image: моя метрика]

Код который непосредственно постит:

```
//ПОСТИНГ В OK
if ($ok_check == 1 || $ok_check == '1' || $ok_stop === 0){
    echo $res->get('id').' - уже публиковался в OK<br>';
} else {
    echo 'OK POST -> '.$res->get('pagetitle').'<br>';
    $post_text= str_replace("%", " процентов", $res->get('description'));
    $params = array(
                    "application_key"=>$ok_public_key,
                    "method"=>"mediatopic.post",
                    "gid"=>"70000003834555",//ID нашей группы
                    "type"=>"GROUP_THEME",
                    "text_link_preview"=>"true",
                    "attachment"=>'{"media": [
                        {"type": "text","text": "'.str_replace('"', "'", $post_text).'"},
                        {"type": "link","url": "'.$post_url.'"}
                    ]}',
                    "format"=>"json"
                   );

    $sig = md5( arr_in_str( $params ) . $ok_session_key  ); //подписываем запрос секретным ключом
    $params["access_token"] = $ok_access_token; //Добавляем наш токен
    $params["sig"] = $sig; //Добавляем полученный хеш

    $result = json_decode( get_url( "https://api.ok.ru/fb.do", "POST", $params), true); //Отправляем пост
    sleep(0.5);
    //Если парсер не смог открыть нашу ссылку (иногда он это делает со второй попытки), то мы получим ошибку 5000, просто отправим запрос ещё разок, этого хватит
    if (isset( $result['error_code'] ) && $result['error_code'] == 5000 ) {
        get_url( "https://api.ok.ru/fb.do", "POST", $params );
        sleep(0.5);
    }
    if (!isset($result['error_code'])){
        if (!$res->setTVValue('ok_check', '1')) {
            $modx->log(xPDO::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'Не удалось изменить значение TV в ресурсе '.$res->get('content'));
        }
    } else {
        if (!$res->setTVValue('ok_check', '3')) {
            $modx->log(xPDO::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'Не удалось изменить значение TV в ресурсе '.$res->get('content'));
        }
    }
    $ok_stop++;
```

Comment: Правьте метрику, чтобы не учитывала бота "Одноклассников"

Comment: Не ужели это не влияет на сео, по 100 отказов вдень из за этого бота. Может стоит его как то запретить?

Comment: А как бот, заходящий на ваш сайт чтобы сделать превью, в принципе может влиять на seo?

Comment: Сори за глупые вопросы, не спец в SEO